Horizontal Line detection and measure distance in between with OpenCV
Hi I'm quite new in OpenCV, I am currently trying to detect horizontal lines in an image using HoughLinesP function in opencv, in order to calculate the ratio between x and y.
The line detection result is shown in the second picture.
original image
result image

How to ignore the vertical lines and only detect horizontal lines?
The egde detected by HoughLinesP seems not a single line. Is there a better way to detect the edge as a single line instead of multiple lines merged together?
How should I proceed to the next step of getting the ratio between x and y?

Thank you in advance!
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('testtube.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 90, 100,apertureSize=3)

# get hough lines
result = img.copy()

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1,theta=np.pi/2, threshold=30,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=30,maxLineGap=20)
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(result, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


bad approach. Hough is a newbie trap. Maslow's hammer. -- please show the original image, not the one where you blanked out the surroundings. -- take a 1-pixel column down the middle of the image. plot it. you'll see.

@ChristophRackwitz, apologize that I don't have the original image, but I found a similar image from the link https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Blood-in-the-vacutainer-tubes-after-centrifugation-at-3000-rpm-for-10-minutes-divided_fig2_236038817 , would you mind explain more, thanks alot

try this on your own picture: profile = gray[:,130]; plt.plot(profile) 130 is the x coordinate of the pixel column. will probably hit the right spot, if your picture is ~260 pixels wide. you're supposed to see a plot line that's 255 first (blank part), then something medium, then almost black (down), then back to white (up) again. then you can use grad = np.gradient(profile) and plot that in a second plot, or in a 2-subplot figure with shared x axis. you'll see peaks. those extrema can be located with scipy.signal.find_peaks.

@by42 I have some important questions here. Is the tube always horizontal in the image ? Is your source image contains the tube alone with white background or is it like the one you shared in the comments ? Your problem gets much more complicated or straightforward depending on the answers.

@ChristophRackwitz, thank you. II think I get your point. The sharp changes in value happen at the edges. I will try that out!

@BarışAktaş The tube will always be placed vertical, I could setup white background to simplify the problem. Just that the two liquids layers could be different color

Okay then if that is the case, i think @ChristophRackwitz's approach is the best, but you have to find the 'x coordinate of the pixel column' automatically, you cant just write 130 and assume it will always coincides with the tube. To find the tube you can again use horizontal profiles, or maybe color filtering if the liquid color is same always.

follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78621736/contour-detection-of-two-adjacent-area

Here is my approach.
1- Check vertically all pixels. Ignore white pixels. Vertically count black pixels(<15), count other non-white pixels. Keep these counts in a variable.
2- Do this for each vertical column which are not white at all. For each columnd counts keep in an array.
3- get the average of all non-black and black pixel counts inside the array. This will statistically give good results.
For the following applied code I get the x and y length as 273.906, 67.3725 respectively. Which are correct results if we check manually.
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('/home/cvlab/Downloads/xy.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.namedWindow('Image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

# Apply median blur
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)

# Initialize lists to store counts
cntsUpper = []
cntsLower = []

# Loop through columns
for i in range(img.shape[1]):
    cntUpper = 0
    cntLower = 0
    for j in range(img.shape[0]):
        pixel_value = img[j, i]
        if 15 < pixel_value < 250:
            cntUpper += 1
        elif pixel_value < 15:
            cntLower += 1

    if cntUpper != 0:
        cntsUpper.append(cntUpper)
    if cntLower != 0:
        cntsLower.append(cntLower)

# Calculate the average for lower counts
if cntsLower:
    averageLower = sum(cntsLower) / len(cntsLower)
    print(f"Average Lower: {averageLower}")

# Calculate the average for upper counts
if cntsUpper:
    averageUpper = sum(cntsUpper) / len(cntsUpper)
    print(f"Average Upper: {averageUpper}")

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

