Contour Detection of two adjacent area
I want to clearly identify and draw the contour of two adjacent liquid layer, the sample image is as shown in the link
sample image
This is what I have tried so far, but the result is far off.
import cv2 
   
image = cv2.imread('input/blood.png') 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
  
# Grayscale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
tube_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

#edged = cv2.Canny(tube_gray, 45, 95)
edged = cv2.Canny(tube_gray, 58, 182) 
# Find Canny edges 

cv2.waitKey(0) 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(9,9))
dilated = cv2.dilate(edged, kernel)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  
cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
  
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours))) 

for cnt in contours:
    print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))

# Draw all contours 
# -1 signifies drawing all contours 
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2) 
  
cv2.imshow('Contours', image) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


filtering by colour will work here. check cv2.inRange(). From this you can create two binary images, one for each contour you want.

Discarding the colour as your first step seems "sub-optimal" as it appears to be  the obvious way to discriminate the two liquids. Try converting to HSV/HSL colourspace and using cv2.inRange() as @TinoD suggests.

follow-up question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78584669/horizontal-line-detection-and-measure-distance-in-between-with-opencv

if you're after the black and yellow areas, they have plenty of contrast. color information would only help you distinguish the yellow stuff from anything else that's bright. -- I would always recommend showing us what you see. don't expect anyone to run your code before you've shown the issue. -- the link to the publication's figure is useful but you should definitely add to your question the picture that you used as input. that way, we can reproduce your issue exactly. that's important.

I would be inclined to convert to HSV colourspace to discriminate the red and yellow areas. If you do that, then separate the H, S and V channels and lay them out left-to-right across the page with ImageMagick:
magick blood.jpeg -colorspace HSV -separate +append result.png


Then you can see that yellow shows up dark in Hue, and light in Saturation and Value. Red shows up as mid-grey in hue and dark in Saturation and Value. It's slightly different in OpenCV but the concept is the same.
So, that leads to code like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image and convert to HSV colourspace
im = cv.imread('blood.jpeg')
HSV = cv.cvtColor(im,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

yellowMin = np.array([10,56,156], np.uint8)
yellowMax = np.array([28,209,239], np.uint8)
yellow = cv.inRange(HSV, yellowMin, yellowMax)
cv.imwrite('yellow.png', yellow)

redMin = np.array([0,0,40], np.uint8)
redMax = np.array([130,60,70], np.uint8)
red = cv.inRange(HSV, redMin, redMax)
cv.imwrite('red.png', red)

And these as the segmented images:



In case you wondered how I determined the ranges to use, here's what I did. I defined the top-left and bottom-right pixel coordinates of the yellow area like this, and cropped the yellow section out:
yellowTop, yellowLeft, yellowBottom, yellowRight = 200, 152, 338, 216
yellow = HSV[yellowTop:yellowBottom, yellowLeft:yellowRight, :]

Then I got the min and max of the H channel:
yellow[...,0].min()
yellow[...,0].max()

then the S channel:
yellow[...,1].min()
yellow[...,1].max()   

and likewise for V channel.
